# How to Increase Java Heap Size directly in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab

I would like to increase the Java heap size directly by Matlab command because I need dynamic control depending on the environment. 
I know the thread [How do I increase the heap space for the Java VM in MATLAB 6.0 (R12) and later versions](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92813-how-do-i-increase-the-heap-space-for-the-java-vm-in-matlab-6-0-r12-and-later-versions) where they say to use `java.opts` file but I would like to do the same with Matlab prompt directly. 
There are many threads that offer to change the parameters only through Matlab GUI or the file, like Matlab's blog post [Controlling the Java Heap Size](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/04/26/controlling-the-java-heap-size/).

I am interested in increasing these parameters dynamically

```
heapSizeMemoryDefault = 521142272; % 512 MB
assert(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory > heapSizeMemoryDefault*2, 'Java heap size too small');
runTimeMemoryDefault = 90116624; % about 890 MB
assert(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory > 90116624*2, 'Java free memory size too small');
```

---

How can you increase Java heap size directly in Matlab 2016a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to change java heap size programmatically, but all require Matlab restart, since heap size is allocated at startup.

To query max heap size *setting* from preferences file:

```
oldMaxHeapSize = com.mathworks.services.Prefs.getIntegerPref('JavaMemHeapMax');  % MB
```

Zero result means there is no setting in the preference file yet, which results in some default size allocated.

To set max heap size *setting* in preferences file:

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setIntegerPref('JavaMemHeapMax', 2048); % MB
```

Remember to restart Matlab, e.g. use `quit()` to end current process. Tested and works on Matlab >= R2013b.

Note that these commands are basically just a programmatic way to edit the `matlab.prf` file, located in Windows installations at (use correct Matlab version) `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013b\matlab.prf`

E.g. in this case, we're editing the following setting (you may open the file after you execute the command to check new value is set)

```
JavaMemHeapMax=I2048
```

There are plenty of other useful settings in the file which can be queried / set in a similar fashion.

Comment: Great! What is the name for the default run time free memory? It should be something double in size by default.

Comment: Free memory is not something you can control with a setting. You control the maximum heap size. As you create java objects during runtime, they are placed on the heap, thus increasing the amount of memory used, and decreasing the amount of free memory that is left. Basically, free memory is the difference between max heap size and memory consumed by all java objects.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you for the clarification! I accept your answer because it answers the question thoroughly.

Comment: This preference was introduced in 2011b. So the solution should work back to that version. Prior to that, direct manipulation of the java.opts file is likely necessary.