# Why savepath resets userpath in Matlab?

Tags: linux, matlab, path

Condition: unsuccessful `userpath` with `addpath` and `savepath`
Differential conditions: unable to start Matlab as sudo/root [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294884/16920)
Support: *MATLAB is not intended to be run by the super user* - Service desk.
Settings

```
echo "export MATLAB_USE_USERWORK=1" >> $HOME/.bashrc    
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r \ 
    "userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/'); exit;"
```

Situations which cause `userpath` to be empty (`''`)

- Test code 1

  ```
  userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/')
  home='/home/masi/';
  savepath(fullfile(home, 'pathdef.m')); 
  % ~/pathdef.m originally but reject because expansion of ~ not working
  userpath
  ```

  Output

  ```
  ''
  ```

  Expected output

  ```
  '/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/:'
  ```

  Complete reiteration from Matlab's prompt after starting Matlab

  ```
  >> userpath

  ans =

  /home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/:

  >> home='/home/masi/';
  >> savepath(fullfile(home, 'pathdef.m'));
  >> userpath

  ans =

       ''
  ```
- Test code 2

  ```
  if (userpath == '')
      userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/')
      addpath('/home/masi/Documents/Math/')
      savepath '/home/masi/pathdef.m'
  end

  % Visualising path in Home > Environment > Set Path
  ```

  Output: `/home/masi/Documents/Math/` stays in path, but `/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/` not. Expected output: both stay in path.
- Test code 3

  ```
  % Edit the Matlab preference file as root. [Kusalananda] 
  % My startup.m
  userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/')
  addpath('/home/masi/Documents/Math/')
  savepath '/home/masi/startup.m'

  % Visualising path in Home > Environment > Set Path
  ```

  Output: `/home/masi/Documents/Math/` stays in path, but `/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/` not. Expected output: both stay in path.
- Test code 4

  ```
  % Use MATLABPATH environment variable instead. [Kusalananda]
  ```

  How?

Matlab: 2016a
System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Related: setup wfdb in Linux [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268931/16920) where the official script is incomplete

Comment: Cannot reproduce running the *exact* code that you have provided.

Comment: I tested on Debian, OS X and Windows. MATLAB 2014a - 2016b. Please actually write the entire script you used above and make it reproducible.

Comment: It your linked answer, of course it doesn't work on OS X because `/home/masi` doesn't exist. It's `/Users/masi`

Comment: Also you do realize that you're saving `pathdef.m` somewhere *other* than the userpath you're setting so it won't be read when MATLAB starts.

Comment: I don't understand why you actually need this. Do you not have root access to the machine where you can modify the `pathdef` for all users?

Comment: So launch MATLAB as root, add the necessary things to the path, save the path you don't have to worry about a `pathdef` file

Comment: Look at what you've typed. The code and the top and the code you've typed in the terminal are different. Just start matlab with `sudo matlab`, add the toolbox to the path with `addpath`, then call `savepath` and don't mess with `pathdef.m` files. I'm not sure how I can make that any clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not maintain stably the `userpath` in the system so a solution which works in the beginning of the functions

```
checkSystemMemory();    
%% TODO Virtual memory; enable virtual memory on HDDs.
% http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388 

home=char(java.lang.System.getProperty('user.home')); % all systems
if (isempty(userpath))
    userpath(fullfile(home, 'Documents/bin/matlab/') ) 
    % list software locations in the project location
    addpath(fullfile(home, 'Documents/Math/') )
    % list software locations in the centralised location
    addpath(fullfile(home, 'Documents/Programming/Matlab/export_fig-master/') )

    % http://stackoverflow.com/a/38188945/54964
    if ( not( com.mathworks.services.Prefs.getStringPref('CurrentKeyBindingSet') == 'Windows' ) ) 
        com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setStringPref('CurrentKeyBindingSet', 'WindowsDefaultSet.xml')
    end 

    % Event errors else with touchpad scroll
    !synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0

    %savepath '/home/masi/pathdef.m'
    savepath(fullfile(home, 'startup.m'));
end

function checkSystemMemory()
%% Java for rdsamp - restart for the change to take effect if necessary.
% https://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/faq.shtml
% http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92813-how-do-i-increase-the-heap-space-for-the-java-vm-in-matlab-6-0-r12-and-later-versions
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/35971040/54964
isSetHeapSizeMemoryMax = com.mathworks.services.Prefs.getIntegerPref('JavaMemHeapMax');  % MB
if (isSetHeapSizeMemoryMax < 2000)
    com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setIntegerPref('JavaMemHeapMax', 2048); % MB
    fprintf('Quitting Matlab Function because memory %d is insufficient.', ...
         isSetHeapSizeMemoryMax);
    return
end
assert(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory/1e9 >= 1.9, 'Java heap size too small');

end
```